# Django 1.7 test error

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to run test on my django app(1.7) but after running `./manage.py test` the following error is appearing :

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "geometry" does not exist`

So basically when I searched, it appears that **gis** extension is missing from postgres. I have installed extension but the error is still the same.

Comment: Uninstall Postgres and install it properly again!

Comment: Are your test settings using the same database type and host as your usual development database?

Comment: i have already reinstall postgres but it did not helped

Comment: @nimasmi i am using the test db of my app for testing

Comment: Did you install the extension to the correct database?  PostgreSQL has the default postgres database in each install, but I'm assuming you have created your own with a different name.  Extension installs are DB specific, so double check that you have installed the extension to your DB.

Comment: the extension is installed in db @GregoryArenius

Comment: @AbijithMg it's bad advice to say uninstall and reinstall

Comment: The problem here is that you appear to be using geodjango. But you haven't got the postgis extensions in your databse. See here how to add them http://postgis.net